# How to handle conflict with curly braces between Laravel and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, laravel

### Can I use Angular JS with Laravel

**Short question:**
How can we use ***Angular JS*** with ***Laravel***, exactly How to handle with curly braces `{{ }}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can **Change the Angular Tags**

Changing the syntax in Angular is very easy. This can be done **when defining your Angular application module** using Angular's `$interpolateProvider`

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});
```

Now Laravel will use the `{{ variableName }}` and Angular will use `<% variableName %>`. Just like that, you can use Laravel Blade and Angular. You can also change this to anything your heart desires.

also u can **Change the Laravel Blade Tags**

Laravel uses **Blade** and Blade comes with a way to change the tags. If you want to keep the Angular syntax default, then use this method.

```
Blade::setContentTags('<%', '%>');        // for variables and all things Blade
Blade::setEscapedContentTags('<%%', '%%>');   // for escaped data
```

more information : [Laravel and Angular Conflicts](https://scotch.io/tutorials/quick-tip-using-laravel-blade-with-angularjs#get-laravel-blade-and-angular-to-play-nicely)

Comment: best way ,that's what I need :)

Answer (score 1):

short answer: **@{{}}**

By the way, you would probably want to try Lumen if you're going to use angular.js with laravel.

Answering the  "Can I use Angular JS with Laravel", the answer is yes. You would probably not use Blade or any other templating engine, but use it to build an API (returning data in JSON format). Then, the Angular.js part would be your frontend app, which is going to be static html, css and js files. You can do some preprocessing to generate those files (with or without laravel).

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks

Comment: Thank you for this , useful.

Comment: this the easiest solution.